# DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR not showing up inside docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am following this [tutorial](https://augustin-riedinger.fr/en/resources/using-docker-as-a-development-environment-part-2/) to set up a Docker environment for a node.js + MongoDB application. As in the tutorial, I am creating two containers: one for node.js script (`node_js` container), and one for MongoDB (`mongo` container).

Accordingly to the tutorial, I should use `DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR` environment variable to perform the connection between `node_js` and `mongo`. However, no value is returned from it:

```
node_js# echo $DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR

node_js#
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:


  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin


  node_js:
    build: ./
    working_dir: /root/node_js
    command: >
      sh -c "npm install
             while sleep 1000; do :; done"
    links:
      - mongo
```

How can I configure the `DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR` variable to connect to `mongo`? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: If your tutorial is recommending those environment variables, it's very old.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the current setup.

Comment: Thanks very much! I followed the link you suggested and could establish a connection to the container correctly.